# Inserting new tuple into sql in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have trouble in inserting a new tuple into my table. It doesn't give any error and I don't know why it doesn't work properly. By the way TextBox3 has something like that: C:\Temp\Pic5.jpg. Here is my code:

```
  protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\MYDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    byte[] data;

    try
    {
        data = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"" + TextBox3.Text);
        string val1 = "" + TextBox1.Text;
        string val2 = "" + TextBox2.Text;
        string val3 = "" + TextBox3.Text;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert INTO Books (Book_Name,Author_Name,Image,In_Lib) VALUES (@BN,@AN,@DATA,@LIB)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BN", val1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AN", val2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA", val3);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LIB", "YES");
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
}
```

asp part

```
Book Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
Author Name:&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
Image Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" Text="Submit" />
<br />
```

My database is like this:

- Book_Name varchar(50)
- Author_Name varchar(50)
- Image image
- In_Lib varchar(50)

Comment: can you show you database table?

Comment: What are data types for that parameters?

Comment: What does `it doesn't work properly` mean? Does nothing get inserted, or just some of the values, or?

Comment: I edited my post again, I put my db elements. It doesn't do anything. I'm clicking the button, then I go to my database. I refresh it. I can't see my new tuple. I have also a link to show all my database in my application. I can see only tuples which are already existiing in my database.

Comment: Oh you Visual Basic victims... `"" + TextBox1.Text` doesn't do anything in C# but cause a pointless memory operation...

Comment: Change your Console.WriteLine to Debug.WriteLine and you might see the exception in your VS Output Window.

Comment: debug it and check whether Textbox value is avialable at runtime or not.

Comment: Try profiling your SQL Server may help you. Are you sure this piece of code even go trought your database? A bit of debug must be done here

Comment: i assume he is storing text value in blob type!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the file specified in `TextBox3.Text` into `data` and not using it anywhere. Also, you're passing text into the `Image` field, you probably wanted to do

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA", data);
```

instead of

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA", val3);
```

Answer (score 2):

As your `Image` column is of type `Image`, the correct parameter value would be a byte array, not a string. This may cause an error. If you are not adding an image right now, leave out this parameter or set it to `DBNull.Value` explicitly.

I presume you're coming from a Visual Basic background (otherwise there's no explanation for the strange `"" + TextBox1.Text` construct), so as a side note: The values passed to the calls to `AddWithValue` should match the column types in the database. By that I mean: Passing a string to a parameter which is of type `int` may work, unless you pass `Hello`. Errors like that are sometimes hard to find, so please: make sure to match parameter types from the beginning.

Comment: Ok thanks Thorsten. I finally found my error.As pjotr said I have to write cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA", data); instead of cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA", val3);

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work

try:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("parameter_name", System.Data.SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = 1233;
```

Comment: This is the same as `AddWithValue` only that you're passing in the type, instead of having it deferred automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is in Image. In database you have database field Image with datatype `Image`, and you are trying to store string data.

```
string val3 = "" + TextBox3.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATA", val3);
```

Make store with `SqlDbType.Image`.